# How to create a custom form that save data to unpublished post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins

I need to create the custom form in Wordpress. The form will allow visitors to fill in the details and the information entered will be saved to an "unpublished" post. Admin will review and publish all the posts that he approves.

Should I create the custom plugin or can it be done in any another way without wordpress developer?

Comment: You can manage using custom code also.

Comment: What do you mean custom code?

Comment: You  got the  solutions or not?

Comment: Finally, I did it.